# How can I access my UINavigationBar properties with this config?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

My main view controller is embedded in a UINavigationController. On my main view I've a button heading to another View Controller, let's call it "settingsController".

The problem is that I changed my UINavigationBar's appearance in my NavigationController (with UIAppearance or subclassing UINavigationBar, nevermind).
But I don't want a custom NavigationBar in my settingsController, where I've no NavigationBar attribute in IB. So how can I change this ?

Thanks for your advices

EDIT : quickly, to sum up this :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any view controller, you can call `self.navigationController.navigationBar` to get the navigation bar of the navigation controller you're currently inside.

You could try changing the appearance in `viewWillAppear` on your settings view controller, and putting it back again in `viewWillDisappear`.